# Parameter value [2020-12-08T07:35] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)] jpa hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.3.1 and JDBC 5.2.7, When I try to query on table using JPA Repo in PostGreSQL DB using `LocalDateTime` as parameter type. It keeps getting this error:

```
Parameter value [2020-12-08T07:35] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
```

I also tried to add Custom Attribute `@Convert` with custom class that converts `LocalDateTime` to `Timestamp` but also not working.

EventEntity.class having attribute as follows:

```
@Column(name = "event_timestamp",nullable = false)
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class)
LocalDateTime eventTimestamp;
```

`CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer` class just serializes datetime value to
`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` using `DateTimeFormatter` to be inserted into column record with this format.

LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter.class that converts as follows:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, java.sql.Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime entityValue) {
        if (entityValue != null) {
            return java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(entityValue);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The class used to search with as follows:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SearchCriteria {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    LocalDateTime eventTimestamp;
}
```

This is query method:

```
public void search(SearchCriteria sc){
    Specification<EventEntity>
    searchCriteria.add(new SearchCriteria("eventTimestamp",          
             SearchOperation.GreaterThanOrEqual , sc.getEventTimestamp()));
    return new SpecificationsBuilder<EventEntity>(searchCriteria).build();
}
SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria();
sc.setEventTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
Specification<EventEntity> searchSpecification = 
          search(sc);
List<EventEntity> entities = repository.findAll(searchSpecification);
```

I implemented this conversion according to research that this version of JPA cannot yet convert automatically to `LocalDateTime` as it is using `java.util.timestamp`.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?